# websocket handshake

Tags: c++, websocket, handshake

I'm writing a websocket server using c++,I was pending in the handshake use chrome 17 as the client.

When the server send client the handshake response chrome always show the error below in console:

Error during WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept mismatch

The event in chrome is as below:

```
t=1328796971951 [st= 5]    WEB_SOCKET_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS  
--> GET / HTTP/1.1   
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:38950
Origin: null     
Sec-WebSocket-Key: zMb+UCeRb+2OmMp9fpbxHw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

t=1328796971951 [st= 5]    SOCKET_STREAM_SENT     
t=1328796971971 [st=25]    SOCKET_STREAM_RECEIVED  
t=1328796971971 [st=25]    WEB_SOCKET_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS  
--> HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 4emBYsdkl0SxeUMGLNc0dFsI1/E=


t=1328796971972 [st=26] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Please help.

Comment: The value you are sending in the accept header is wrong. You need to show your code for calculating the accept value otherwise we have no idea what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks , You are right ,The server send the wrong key.

Comment: When  calculate the key,the input key is ended with '/r/n',and this is the reason why I always the the wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` value is not correctly calculated.

## How to calculate the value (pseudocode):

```
// Getting the Sec-WebSocket-Key from the Request header
var sec_Websocket_Key = requestHeader["Sec-WebSocket-Key"];
// Adding the magic string to sec_Websocket_key
// sha1 hash this new value
var sec_Websocket_Key_Hash = (sec_Websocket-Key + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11").sha1();
// Get the Base64 String of the hash
var sec_Websocket_Accept = sec_Websocket_Key_Hash.toBase64String();
// sec_Websocket_Accept now is the correct value to set in the Header
```

Get more informations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers)